# What is special about com.oracle:ojdbc6 in version 11.2.0.3?

Tags: oracle, maven, repository, licensing, ojdbc

Because of Oracle licensing policy each organization import Oracle JDBC driver into in-house Repository Manager.

But `com.oracle:ojdbc6` at version `11.2.0.3` is available on public repositories (and many more):

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3
- https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.oracle:ojdbc6

Is that pirate copy / unlicensed / unauthorized use of `ojdbc6.jar`?

Comment: No, Oracle has decided to release the JAR on public Maven repositories https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for.

Comment: What to say? I am surprised )) Still it is unclear conditions of using https://maven.oracle.com/ and is it legal to mirror this repository. But for testing purpose it is very convenient to have `ojdbc6`/`ojdbc7` in public repos.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks **@Tunaki** for the link. Oracle open access to some JDBC drivers via http://maven.oracle.com/

Announce and conditions can be fount at https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc

As say that page:

> Step#2: Registering with the Oracle Maven site
>   The Oracle Maven repository requires a valid user registration and the user should also accept the terms and conditions (T&Cs) by logging into http://maven.oracle.com . This username will be used in settings.xml.

So distribution of copies across the Internet (like in bintray.com) is somewhat illegal but convenient ))

Another post about JDBC driver availability: https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for

Comment: what is the license for ojdbc?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that maven.oracle.com is the officially supported maven repository.  We have 12.1.0.1 and 12.1.0.2 JDBC drivers on this repository.

Any other repository is not the official distribution channel. 
The [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc) clarifies the steps required to download the JDBC driver.